# Circleprogress Problem in Android Studio Arctic Fox

Tags: java, android

I am using Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) & Android Gradle plugin 7.0 in Java.
Before this version I used very well in Circleprogress.
now in this version in is not recognized.
the error I get is:

```
Could not resolve all files for configuration :app:debugRuntimeClasspath.
Could not find com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.0.
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Just change the `Dependency` and `Sync Now`

```
implementation 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'
```

**Version Source :-** https://jitpack.io/#lzyzsd/CircleProgress

Comment: still not working. the problem is, that you can not add  allprojects { repositories { in gradle:7.0.0 the new version of android Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) . try it in a new project.

Comment: I have found the solution. I had to Disable repositories in settings.gradle. dependencyResolutionManagement {
//repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)

Comment: new version also available `v1.2.1`